# Cleanly Remove MAMP Pro

Tags: macos, terminal.app, rm

I'm trying to cleanly remove MAMP Pro from my Mac and I'm following the steps outlined in the SO article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855247/mamp-pro-restore-root-user-uninstall.

I have been able to perform everything except one piece -- I can't remove the `hosts.mamp.bak` file because I get a `Permission denied` error.

I'm trying to remove it from the `Terminal` app.

Do I need to login to the `Terminal` app some special way?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

`sudo rm /etc/hosts.mamp.bak`

and then type your password when prompted.

For more on `sudo`, [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo).

Comment: Okay, so `sudo` causes it to ask for elevated permissions?

Comment: Yes.  [Sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) causes the given command to run with root privileges.

Comment: we all started somewhere.  Good luck.  And pay special attention when using Sudo.  As the old prompt says, with great power comes great responsibility.   You can truly #&$% up your system in a hurry, so always double check commands, and always maintain backups.